# How can I improve OCR recognition?

Tags: c#, ocr, tesseract, emgucv

I'm having trouble correctly recognizing this kind of words as you can see in the picture

[image: Image to recognize]

And in the result i have this:

```
RMACWI O
12X60
VPFZZOOIK
IADA50527
PORTES
```

I'm using these variables

```
ocr.SetVariable("tessedit_pageseg_mode", 10);
ocr.SetVariable("tessedit_char_whitelist", "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789/-,.€");
```

Is there a way of improving recognition?

Later I have binarised the image, but the resul it was worst!

[image]

The result:

```
RMACW1 0
TZXW
VPFZZDWK
IADASDEU
PORTES
```

Answer (score 2):

You can fiddle with pre-processing the image, but you could save a lot of time by changing your OCR engine to [Google cloud vision](https://cloud.google.com/vision/). When I ran your image it detected the text perfectly:

```
RMAC6010
12X60
VPF3200/K
IADA50527
PORTES
Documentos refer
Enc. Cli EC19/041
```

Google cloud is a bit of a pain to get set up but their AI APIs are the best in the world. You can test your image [here](https://cloud.google.com/vision/). They have client libraries for all the major languages.

[Google Cloud Vision Quick-start](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/pdf)
[OCR w/ gcloud documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/pdf)

Comment: I agree on this one, Tesseract never will be perfect and will always mistake certain characters for another. Yet, not in every scenario it's possible to use a service like this due to regulations.

Comment: Ah, yes their TOS are quite strict and you might not be able to send the data to the cloud. I suppose if you want to invest the time you could use a paid service as ground truth and retrain your own tesseract weights. I haven't had great results with retaining though, and it takes a lot of time.

Comment: @Viezevingertjes thank you for the answer. Probably the solution won't exceed  1000 times per month... so that's a nice option

Answer (score 0):

Cropping, thresholding and resizing the image could help. Tesseract works best for black text on white background. Check [this](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/ImproveQuality) site for more information.

Comment: I tried binarize image, but the result was worst. Look at my question now

Comment: You could still try cropping and resizing the image. Why are you using pagesegmode 10? It indicates "treat the image as a single character". You should be using 6, or, if you crop the image into rows, 7

Comment: How can I crop image into multiple rows?

Comment: Just cut the image so that one image only has one row of numbers. You could use snipping tool, or many free options to do so.

Comment: Adding to @JavierUrrestarazu answer, you can also smoothen the image as the last step before feeding it to OCR

Answer (score 0):

You can apply a slight Gaussian blur to the binary image. This will help to smooth the image. Here's the result:

[image]

Result from OCR

```
RMAC6010

12X60

VPF3200/K
\ADA50527

PORTES
Documentos refe:
Ene. Cli EC 19/041
```

I implemented it in Python OpenCV + Pytesseract but you can adapt the same strategy into C#

```
import cv2
import pytesseract

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r"C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe"

# Load image and Otsu's Threshold to get a binary image
image = cv2.imread('1.jpg', 0)
thresh = cv2.threshold(image, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# Gaussian blur and then perform OCR
thresh = cv2.GaussianBlur(thresh, (3,3), 0)
data = pytesseract.image_to_string(thresh, lang='eng', config='--psm 6')
print(data)

cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Right now i'm using  `System.Drawing.Size kSize = new System.Drawing.Size(3, 3);
            Image<Gray, byte> grayImg = temp.Convert<Gray, byte>();
            Image<Gray, byte> binImg = new Image<Gray, byte>(grayImg.Size);
            Image<Gray, byte> gaussImg = new Image<Gray, byte>(grayImg.Size);
            CvInvoke.Threshold(grayImg, binImg, 0, 255, ThresholdType.Binary | ThresholdType.Otsu);
            CvInvoke.GaussianBlur(binImg,gaussImg, kSize, 0);` But the result is not like yours ....

Comment: The C# OpenCV implementation may be different from the Python version